# I need data from a csv file which is not present in the second csv file

Tags: shell, csv, uniq

For example: I have  a CSV file (first file ) with below data (vertically):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Second CSV with below data (vertically):

```
5
6
7
8
```

I want my resultant file (action needs to be performed using Unix shell scripting) to show only values (vertically) in first file but not in second file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Does each file have only one column? Are both files sorted already?

Comment: yes both files have only 1 column and we can sort using sort command

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the files are in sorted order you can use the `comm` command to compare the 2 files and show the results that are in `file1` but not in `file2`.

```
$ comm -23 file1 file2
1
2
3
4
```

The `-23` switch tells `comm` to omit the lines that are only in file2 (`-2`) and the lines that are in both (`-3`).

Comment: This won't work properly with actual CSV-formatted data, which can contain newlines inside quoted column values.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command :

`diff file1 file2 | grep '<' | cut -c3-`

The diff takes the difference of the files file1 and file2 , then we `grep '<'` the output of the first command to get the lines that belong to the first file only. The output is then fed to `cut -c3-`to truncate the first two characters so that '<' and ' ' are eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Pass one file as a pattern to `grep`:

```
grep -vwFf 2.csv 1.csv 
1
2
3
4
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
          contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
          specified by POSIX.)
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
          is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Oh baby you're in the final stretch for 20k now 8-)